# Swiftyjson bundled file

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

Ok i have a bundled .json file that I am looking to parse with swifty json. The model I am using in swifty json is a top level object that has an array of objects that each contain values of either strings or ints. I was wondering what code I need to create in order to make this. Anyone help in this matter is appreciated. I am new to coding in general and while I actually understand the sequence of most coding this parse function is a bit difficult for me to really grasp. If someone could make me a example code and explain what each part of it does that would be extremely helpful. Lets say I just want to pull one value out of one of the objects and use put it in an array to display in a uitableview. Hope this was clear and any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok:

1. Read out your file

   ```
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename", ofType: "json")
   let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
   ```
2. load data to SwiftyJSON

   ```
   let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
   ```
3. Get the Object you want:

   ```
   let name = json["key1"]["key2"].stringValue // get any value
   ```
4. Or cast as Array

   ```
   if let array = json["key_of_array"].array{
       if let string = array[0].string{

       // get the first value of an array as string, if there is another key, use: array[0]["key_of_subelement"].string

       }
   }
   ```

And check out this:

http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/swiftyjson-how-to-handle-json-in-swift/111

Here you find some easy ways to read out all data you need

Comment: Thank you for switch quick feedback the problem I run into every time I try and implement this function of code in a func or outside of the a func the let jsonData = NSData.dataWithContentOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil0 part of the code gives me a error that its a value of optional type that needs to be unwrapped with ! or ?. When I put either of these in for the path it gives me a different error stating dataWithContentOfFile is unavailable use NSData(contentsOfFile:options:error:).

Comment: Also for #3 in your list lets say for instance i want to pull out the same string type from multiple objects in an array? Sorry if this is a stupid question will it automatically display the strings for multiple objects in line? or do i have to pull out individually for each object?

Comment: You need to iterate through an array, and read out all Objects. Check out my link, like here (see edit)

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses I am going to go read up on that link. Hopefully if I can get this part of my project complete I will be able to use these functions more often. I am self teaching. Unfortunately that involves a lot of researching outdated info.

Comment: Good luck, and feel free to ask here again. But normally you should try to solve things at your own first, and ask more specific.

Comment: Alright well after a ton of reading and actually learning as much as I can about this, I am still having troubles. The json file I made is completely deciphered and is actually printing to the logs but when I try to parse the key i want like you demonstrated i get a nil value. It is just a simple string. I am at a loss for what to try next.

Comment: And your JSON is valid? Check with: http://jsoneditoronline.org/ - and Post some Code (or create a new question)

Comment: Yes it is valid I don't mind send you a copy of it as it doesn't contain any valuable information

Comment: Create a new Question, maybe i can help you.

Comment: [
  {
    "Attack": 4,
    "Card Description": "<b>Deathrattle</b>Deal 2 damage to ALL other characters.",
    "Card Type": "0",
    "Class": "10",
    "Cost": 5,
    "Health": 4,
    "Name": "Abomination",
    "Rarity": 3
  },
  {
    "Class": "1",
    "Name": "Fiery War Axe",
    "Cost": 2,
    "Card Type": 2,
    "Card Description": "",
    "Rarity": 5
  },
]

Comment: Please create a new question, is not helpful to write this in comments (for another users maybe with the same problem)

Comment: created the new question it is called swiftyjson bundled file not parsing